# multiple tables from the same model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am attempting to use several tables that all follow the same model, this is so that eventually if my application scales farther than needing a single database, the framework has already been laid.

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'Entity' and 'Reddit' can both contain instances of type 'Project.Models.Entity'.

I know this error comes from this section of my dbcontect model:

```
public DbSet<Entity> Entity {get; set;} //local users
public DbSet<Entity> Reddit { get; set; } //users who registered through reddit
public DbSet<Entity> Twitter { get; set; } //user who registered through twitter
```

I cant seem to find a way to make this work. I know existing topics cover why this is a problem, but the only solution I seem to find is "well make another database" which while seems simple, still doesn't really explain the issue or how to actually fix it through code.

(using entity framework 6)

Comment: please update your question with which ORM specifically it looks like Entity Framework, and which version you're using.

Comment: as a variant you can use separate db context for each table

Comment: I have moved the "answer" portion of your post to the answers section. You can post answers, even on your own questions. It is highly encouraged that you do this when you solve your own problem.

Comment: @OleksiiAza I ended up doing this, but now it seems like the mapping is wrong. even if i do a where in _RDB.Reddit, it looks in dbo.Entities. what would be the best way to override the default mapping?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>This was extracted from the question.</sub>

---

I found the solution and It's so simple I'm rather ashamed that I even had to ask.

just make a new DBcontext for each table
which looks like

RedditDB.cs

```
public RedditDB() : base("name=Database")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Entity> Reddit { get; set; }
```

TwitterDB.cs

```
public RedditDB() : base("name=Database")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Entity> Twitter{ get; set; }
```

and in the controller just put

```
RedditDB _RDB = new RedditDB();
TwitterDB _TDB = new TwitterDB();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance to create a new class with the same properties as the existing Entity.

```
public class Twitter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EntityC> Lines { get; set; }
}
public class Reddit : Twitter
{
    // leave this empty
}
```

This is better than using separate DB contexts because it is easier to query a single context; you can join tables etc.